# Java PriorityBlockingQueue blocking behavior

Tags: java, priority-queue, blockingqueue

From the docs I see, that the `take()` method blocks until an element becomes available.
Is there any other scenario when it could block?

What I mean is, is there a possible scenario, when the queue is **not** empty, but despite that, calling `take()` blocks for some reason.

Please tell me, if anyone has knowledge about some scenario like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other scenario when it could block?

By my reading of the code (Java 11 version) `take()` *should* only block if the queue is empty when the call is made.

But that doesn't imply that a `take()` call will immediately unblock when the queue becomes non-empty.  Indeed, if two or more threads are calling `take()` at the same time, it is conceivable that some threads will "starve" because the arriving elements are consistently being delivered to other waiting threads.   (The `PriorityBlockingQueue` uses `ReentrantLock` instances to coordinate the producers and consumers, but these are not created as *fair* locks.)

Another scenario involves faulty `Comparable` or `Comparator` implementations.  When the queue is or becomes non-empty, `take()` calls an internal `dequeue` method which in turn uses the `Comparable` or `Comparator` interface to *sift* the queue.  If your `Comparable` or `Comparator` code could itself block, that would block the current `take()` call and all future `take()` calls.

---

Having said that, you also need to consider the most obvious explanation; i.e. that `take()` is blocking because the queue *really is empty*.